# Group documents based on field on another collection Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 collections

**Quizzes**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "quiz1",
    "tags": "tag1",
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "quiz2",
    "tags": "tag1"
  }
]
```

**Users**

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "name": "Mike"
}
```

**Answers**

```
[
  {
   _id: 1,
   "relatedUser": 1,
   "relatedQuiz": 1,
   "result": 10
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    "relatedUser": 1,
    "relatedQuiz": 2,
    "result": 20
  }
]
```

**And need the Result to be**

```
{
   "tags": "tag1",
   "relatedUser": "Mike",
   "totalResult": 30
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline on the `answers` collection to get the desired result.

1. Start with a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage to fetch the quiz tags for each document in the `answers` collection.
2. Use an [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to return an output document for each quiz document.
3. Introduce a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to group the documents by `relatedUser` and `quiz.tags` fields and compute the sum of `result` using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).
4. Add another [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  stage to fetch the user document from the `users` collection.
5. Use another [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to return an output document for each user document.
6. Finish with a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to return the fields you're interested in.

```
db.answers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'quizzes',
      localField: 'relatedQuiz',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'quiz',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$quiz',
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        userId: '$relatedUser',
        tags: '$quiz.tags',
      },
      score: {
        $sum: '$result',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: '_id.userId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'user',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$user',
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      tags: '$_id.tags',
      relatedUser: '$user.name',
      totalResult: '$score',
    },
  },
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EyOGf-ofNtB)

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i got this result  [
  {
    tags: [ 'tag3', 'tag1', 'tag2' ],
    relatedUser: 'Mike',
    totalResult: 94
  }
]    and i need group by tags[
  {
    tags: 'tag1',
    relatedUser: 'Mike',
    totalResult: 10 (total results of tag1)
  },
  {
    tags: 'tag2',
    relatedUser: 'Mike',
    totalResult: 20 (total results of tag2)
  },

]

Comment: @beshoygamal Ah, that wasn't clear from the question. Let me update my answer.